# How to make ansible loop over hosts sequentially

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have set of tasks that i want to execute at set of hosts sequentially.

Example is below.

```
hosts: all
tasks:
- name: do some work
  include_tasks: tasks_here.yml
  loop: "{{ vars[play_hosts] }}"

ansible-playbook main.yml --limit myhosts
```

I expect that set of tasks would be executed at first host, then at second host etc...  But in fact these tasks are being executed simulatineously at all hosts in "limit".
I suspect that it's happening because I use limit but i need it in my case.

So what I should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, as specified [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html):

> plays run with a linear strategy, in which all hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task.

You can use the strategy `serial: 1` to execute the tasks on each host sequentially.

For example:

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. So I don't need loop at all if I use 'serial:1' execution strategy. Am I right?